# Launch Teams Application from Browser

Tags: reactjs, typescript, microsoft-teams

I want to open Teams Desktop Application from Browser Pop-up like this.
[Open Microsoft Teams Application Pop-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWfPf.png)

Is there a way to do that in my React.js/typescript web application?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a [hyperlink with the correct structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links), then your browser will show the appropriate pop-up and Teams will handle it:

```
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/<appId>/<entityId>?webUrl=<entityWebUrl>&label=<entityLabel>&context=<context>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#deep-linking-to-a-chat)

Example : https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users=joe@contoso.com,bob@contoso.com&topicName=Prep%20For%20Meeting%20Tomorrow&message=Hi%20folks%2C%20kicking%20off%20a%20chat%20about%20our%20meeting%20tomorrow

Above example solved my problem thanks!